# Saving Outlook email as PDF + Attachments, without overwriting when names are duplicated

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I save incoming mail with an inbox rule and VBA code.

When there are multiple emails with the same name and also if the attachments have the same name they overwrite each other.

I need both the email and the attachments to loop through 1-10. There can be up to ten emails and attachments with the same names.

```vb
Sub SaveAsMsg(MyMail As MailItem)
' requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' \Windows\System32\Scrrun.dll
' Also requires reference to Microsoft Word Object Library
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strSaveName As String
Dim blnOverwrite As Boolean
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim looper As Integer
Dim strID As String
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
  
strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
  
'Get Sender email domain
sendEmailAddr = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
companyDomain = Right(sendEmailAddr, Len(sendEmailAddr) - InStr(sendEmailAddr, "@"))
  
' ### USER OPTIONS ###
blnOverwrite = False ' False = don't overwrite, True = do overwrite
  
'### THIS IS WHERE SAVE LOCATIONS ARE SET ###
'Currently only saves to yPath. Change the yPath variable to mPath in other areas of the script to enable the month folder.
bPath = "C:\email\" 'Defines the base path to save the email
cPath = bPath & companyDomain & "\" 'Adds company domain to base path
yPath = cPath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\" 'Add year subfolder
mPath = yPath & Format(Now(), "MMMM") & "\" 'Add month subfolder
  
'### Path Validity ###
'Make sure base path exists
If Dir(bPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
   MkDir bPath
End If
'Make sure company domain path exists
'If Dir(cPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
   'MkDir cPath
'End If
'Make sure year path exists
'If Dir(yPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
   'MkDir yPath
'End If
'Make sure month path exists (uncomment below lines to enable)
'If Dir(mPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
 'MkDir mPath
'End If
 
'### Get Email subject & set name to be saved as ###
emailSubject = CleanFileName(oMail.Subject)
saveName = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & emailSubject & ".txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  
'### If don't overwrite is on then ###
If blnOverwrite = False Then
   looper = 0
   Do While fso.FileExists(yPath & saveName)
      looper = looper + 1
      saveName = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & emailSubject & "_" & looper & ".txt"
   Loop
Else '### If don't overwrite is off, delete the file ###
   If fso.FileExists(yPath & saveName) Then
      fso.DeleteFile yPath & saveName
   End If
End If
 
'### Save MSG File ###
oMail.SaveAs bPath & saveName, olTXT
  
'### If Mail Attachments: clean file name, save into path ###
If oMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
   For Each atmt In oMail.Attachments
      atmtName = CleanFileName(atmt.FileName)
      atmtSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd") & "_" & atmtName
      atmt.SaveAsFile atmtSave
   Next
End If
  
Set oMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub


Function CleanFileName(strText As String) As String
Dim strStripChars As String
Dim intLen As Integer
Dim i As Integer
strStripChars = "/\[]:=," & Chr(34)
intLen = Len(strStripChars)
strText = Trim(strText)
For i = 1 To intLen
strText = Replace(strText, Mid(strStripChars, i, 1), "")
Next
CleanFileName = strText
End Function


Sub SaveAsPDF(MyMail As MailItem)
' requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
' \Windows\System32\Scrrun.dll
' Also requires reference to Microsoft Word Object Library
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strSaveName As String
Dim blnOverwrite As Boolean
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim looper As Integer
Dim strID As String
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
 
strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
 
'Get Sender email domain
sendEmailAddr = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
companyDomain = Right(sendEmailAddr, Len(sendEmailAddr) - InStr(sendEmailAddr, "@"))
 
' ### USER OPTIONS ###
blnOverwrite = False ' False = don't overwrite, True = do overwrite
 
'### THIS IS WHERE SAVE LOCATIONS ARE SET ###
bPath = "C:\email\" 'Defines the base path to save the email
cPath = bPath & companyDomain & "\" 'Adds company domain to base path
yPath = cPath & Format(Now(), "yyyy") & "\" 'Add year subfolder
mPath = yPath & Format(Now(), "MMMM") & "\" 'Add month subfolder
 
'### Path Validity ###
If Dir(bPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MkDir bPath
End If
'If Dir(cPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
   ' MkDir cPath
'End If
'If Dir(yPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
   ' MkDir yPath
'End If
 
'### Get Email subject & set name to be saved as ###
emailSubject = CleanFileName(oMail.Subject)
saveName = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & emailSubject & ".mht"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
'### If don't overwrite is on then ###
If blnOverwrite = False Then
    looper = 0
    Do While fso.FileExists(bPath & saveName)
        looper = looper + 1
        saveName = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & emailSubject & "_" & looper & ".mht"
        pdfSave = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & emailSubject & "_" & looper & ".pdf"
        Loop
Else '### If don't overwrite is off, delete the file ###
    If fso.FileExists(bPath & saveName) Then
        fso.DeleteFile bPath & saveName
    End If
End If
oMail.SaveAs bPath & saveName, olMHTML
pdfSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & emailSubject & ".pdf"
 
'### Open Word to convert file to PDF ###
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
 
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=bPath & saveName, Visible:=True)
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
            pdfSave, ExportFormat:= _
            wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
            wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
 
wrdDoc.Close
wrdApp.Quit
 
'### Clean up files ###
With New FileSystemObject
    If .FileExists(bPath & saveName) Then
        .DeleteFile bPath & saveName
    End If
End With
 
'### If Mail Attachments: clean file name, save into path ###
If oMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
    For Each atmt In oMail.Attachments
        atmtName = CleanFileName(atmt.FileName)
        atmtSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & atmtName
        atmt.SaveAsFile atmtSave
    Next
End If
 
Set oMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use the `Dir` function to test whether file already exists. If it already exists, then you need to give it a new filename.

Comment: Would I have to create unique identifiers, or could I loop through ~10 numbers to add at the end of the file names?

Comment: Why don't you try a few things and see what works (or doesn't)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed the following lines of code:

```
strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)
```

There is no need to get a new instance of the MailItem class. You can use the instance passed as a parameter.

```
 If fso.FileExists(bPath & saveName) Then
    fso.DeleteFile bPath & saveName
```

It looks like you delete existing files instead of saving a new ones with different names.

You may consider using the datetime (not only the date) marker when saving emails/attachments. Or you may check out whether such file exists on the disk already.

Comment: Thanks for the help! What is the difference between oMail.RecievedTime and datetime? I have it saving the files down to the second but, when they are sent all at once, sometimes the files are not saved.

Comment: I deleted the code that deletes the file but I don't understand the first part of your answer (i'm somewhat new to vba).  which of that is the new instance of the MailItem class and should some of it be deleted?? please see my answer below and let me know how to improve what I have there.

Answer (score 2):

This works really well once you delete the `if` statements that delete the file.  Thank you for the foundation.

I've modified the PDF portion of your code (for the better, I hope) and fixed an issue that the pdf filename would not increment if it existed already.  I had to write a separate loop for the PDF because you basically stopped the loop with this line: `pdfSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & emailSubject & ".pdf"` but I can't seem to get rid of that line without producing an error so made a new loop.  Maybe someone can simplify that part for me.

I've also added a line to delete the `.mht` file only used to create the PDF and modified the filenames a bit:

```
Function CleanFileName(strText As String) As String
Dim strStripChars As String
Dim intLen As Integer
Dim i As Integer
strStripChars = "/\[]:=," & Chr(34)
intLen = Len(strStripChars)
strText = Trim(strText)
For i = 1 To intLen
strText = Replace(strText, Mid(strStripChars, i, 1), "")
Next
CleanFileName = strText
End Function



Sub SaveAsPDF(MyMail As MailItem)
' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime ###
' ### Requires reference to Microsoft Word Object Library ###
' --- In VBE click TOOLS > REFERENCES and check the boxes for both of the above ---
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strSaveName As String
Dim blnOverwrite As Boolean
Dim strFolderPath As String
Dim sendEmailAddr As String
Dim senderName As String
Dim looper As Integer
Dim plooper As Integer
Dim strID As String
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim bPath, EmailSubject, saveName, pdfSave As String

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

' ### Get username portion of sender email address ###
sendEmailAddr = oMail.SenderEmailAddress
senderName = Left(sendEmailAddr, InStr(sendEmailAddr, "@") - 1)

' ### USER OPTIONS ###
blnOverwrite = False ' False = don't overwrite, True = do overwrite

' ### Path to save directory ###
bPath = "Z:\email\"

' ### Create Directory if it doesnt exist ###
If Dir(bPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MkDir bPath
End If

' ### Get Email subject & set name to be saved as ###
emailSubject = CleanFileName(oMail.Subject)
saveName = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & emailSubject & ".mht"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' ### Increment filename if it already exists ###
If blnOverwrite = False Then
    looper = 0
    Do While fso.FileExists(bPath & saveName)
        looper = looper + 1
        saveName = Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & senderName & "_" & emailSubject & "_" & looper & ".mht"
        Loop
Else
End If

' ### Save .mht file to create pdf from Word ###
oMail.SaveAs bPath & saveName, olMHTML
pdfSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & senderName & "_" & emailSubject & ".pdf"

If fso.FileExists(pdfSave) Then
    plooper = 0
    Do While fso.FileExists(pdfSave)
    plooper = plooper + 1
    pdfSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & senderName & "_" & emailSubject & "_" & plooper & ".pdf"
    Loop
Else
End If

    
' ### Open Word to convert .mht file to PDF ###
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

' ### Open .mht file we just saved and export as PDF ###
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=bPath & saveName, Visible:=True)
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
            pdfSave, ExportFormat:= _
            wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
            wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

wrdDoc.Close
wrdApp.Quit

' ### Delete .mht file ###
Kill bPath & saveName

' ### Uncomment this section to save attachments ###
'If oMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
'    For Each atmt In oMail.Attachments
'        atmtName = CleanFileName(atmt.FileName)
'        atmtSave = bPath & Format(oMail.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm") & "_" & atmtName
'        atmt.SaveAsFile atmtSave
'    Next
'End If

Set oMail = Nothing
Set olNS = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```